# nested navbar doesn't align under main nav

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, nav

Hello I'm trying to add a nested nav in my main nav. The problem is the nested nav doesn't align properly under the main nav. Please see the screenshot. The nested nav doesn't align right under the main nav. The nested nav moved around 50% to the right. I'm using css flexbox to layout the nav.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: red; /* to see menu */
}

.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 8rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.heading a:link,
a:visited {
  font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.heading a:hover,
a:active {
  transform: translate(.3rem, -.2rem);
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 45%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.nested {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.nested li {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar li a:link,
a:visited {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover,
a:active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.082);
}

.toggler {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <h1 class="heading"><a href="#">HeaderName</a></h1>
  <div class="toggler">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#"> Home</a>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i> About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-concierge-bell"></i> Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i> About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-concierge-bell"></i> Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So do you want the nested nav to be 100% width under the main nav, or do you want aligned under Home in this case? Or both?

Comment: hello, i want it to align under home and taking same width as main nav's li

Comment: Please see the screenshot . the nested nav should take proper alignment under main nav and should take equal width as home takes. it's a dropdown...

Comment: i think the nested nav have some padding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the got the problem. there was padding on the nested nav. had to add padding:0 property to css. My suggestion is to add margin:0 and padding:0 to ul, li ,a  property.